# Get month number from month name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Quick question, I have  a list of months by name i.e. "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" ... etc. that I want to convert into 1,2,3,4 ... etc. I have written some simple code to do this but was just curious if anyone knew a way to do this using any of the APIs.

Comment: Given that in French April would be Avr, not to mention Japanese or Arabic, I think you're underestimating the issue of localization in this question ;)

Comment: I am just reading from an existing data table, so my months will always be the English "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" ... format, but thats certainly a going point to keep in mind depending on where the data might be coming from.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
NSDate *aDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"Jul"];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:aDate];
NSLog(@"Month: %i", [components month]); /* => 7 */
```

See [date formatters](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class Ref. That would be the class you might want to consider using.

Comment: Much appreciated, missed that one, checked NSDate and NSCalendar, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get a number is to get the index, that if the list of months is ordered:

`NSLog(@"The number of the month is: %d.",[listOfMonths indexOfObject:@"Jan"]+1);`

There's nothing more direct than this.

Comment: Thats a good point, I could certainly create an array and use that to look up the month index. Nice quick idea, thank you.

Comment: I'm curious now, what's the solution you came up with.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift User you can use:

```
Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date)
Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4, This works for me perfectly.

```
Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date())
Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date())
```