# Convert long month name to int

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter, date-parsing

I understand how to use an `NSDateFormatter` to convert a month component into a long name string, but how does one convert a month name to an `int`?

I've been using a switch statement to convert, but I'm thinking there must be a simpler way.

For example, I'd like to convert "May" to 5.

Comment: The correct procedure is here: [Get month number from month name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9114829), though it's written in ObjC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MM` for the month format. Use `stringFromDate` to convert your `NSDate` to a `String`. Then convert your string to an `Int` with `.toInt()`

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM"
let monthString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()) // "05"
let monthInt = monthString.toInt() // 5
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use DateFormatter custom format `"LLLL"` to parse your date string (Month). If you are only parsing dates in english you should set the date formatter locale to `"en_US_POSIX"`:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
df.dateFormat = "LLLL"  // if you need 3 letter month just use "LLL"
if let date = df.date(from: "May") {
    let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date)
    print(month)  // 5
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Josh. I've converted the Obj-C code and posted it below for future reference:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let components = NSDateComponents()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
let aDate = formatter.dateFromString("May")
let components1 = calendar!.components(.CalendarUnitMonth , fromDate: aDate!)
let monthInt = components.month
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSDateFormatter` has [`monthSymbols` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDateFormatter/monthSymbols). Try:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

let monthString = "September"
let month = find(formatter.monthSymbols as! [String], monthString).map { $0 + 1 }
// -> Optional(9)

let monthString2 = "Foobar"
let month2 = find(formatter.monthSymbols as! [String], monthString2).map { $0 + 1 }
// -> nil
```